# Howto use PostgreSQL table names without double quotes in C# and Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

i'm trying to select data from PostgreSQL 10.5 database with Npgsql2 library - I cannot use Npgsql3 or Npgsql4 because I need to support Windows XP (.NET 4.0 maximum).
I use the following code:

```
var builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
//setting connection string variables here
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(builder.Tostring());
var query = "SELECT * FROM \"TableName\" ORDER BY \"ColumnName\"";
var adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
var dataSet = new DataSet();

connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

If I don't use double quotes for TableName or ColumnName in my query - it fails with error:

> PostgreSQL ERROR: 42P01: relation “TableName” does not exist

With double quotes it works.

So is it possible to use Npgsql without double quotes? Is there some flag or something?

Comment: Is `TableName` the actual name of the table, or is it something else?

Comment: You need double quotes to make the name case sensitive. If your table name is in fact `TableName`, you will need double quotes to keep the uppercase characters, otherwise it will try to read a table called `tablename`.

Comment: İf database is in your hand and you can change table and column names then when you lowercase all of them then the problem will be solved. you can reach your table with select * from tablenameİ statement

Comment: TableName is the actual name of the table. Unfortunatelly I cannot change database schema, so looks like that double quotes is the only solution. Thx to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without double quotes, PostgreSQL folds all identifiers to lower-case. This is PostgreSQL behavior, and has nothing to do with Npgsql - the latter simply passes along your SQL as you wrote it. You can switch to all-lowercase table names, in which case you no longer need the quotes.